# Como inserir linhas nos gráficos para denotar diferenças post-hoc entre grupos comparados?

Tags: r, ggplot2, anova, rgraph

Eu preciso identificar graficamente as diferenças post-hoc entre comparações de médias. Tal como a figura abaixo:

[image: Percebam as linhas em cima dos box-plots e asteriscos que denotam a significância]

Envio um dput com dados simples para facilitar a geração de gráfico (não é o da figura), bem como a base de gráfico para que seja continuado.

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Grupo = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(1.14901252600116, 2.2759735134712, 1.65553164019443, 
    1.56369896215724, 2.72398274895494, 2.48108360073242, 2.26546377144311, 
    2.33209770776873, 2.28731709992939, 1.81524976926264, 3.09226862162988, 
    3.79822202874918, 3.71669618296597, 4.00204796633077, 4.47209295173977, 
    4.33828240733588, 3.83323798255772, 4.20237841036556, 4.27585406310512, 
    4.01484026647116, 7.7037558305269, 7.79523829060191, 8.44198516477667, 
    8.76460991202211, 8.92519252259177, 7.66958621885233, 7.38649721403375, 
    7.29882998824104, 7.33562774857289, 7.48731319375855)), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = "data.frame")


pl <- ggplot(df,aes(x = Grupo, y = value, fill = Grupo)) + geom_boxplot()
```

Tenho conhecimento que o software graphpad prism executa isso com certa facilidade. Mas, como todos sabem ele tem um custo elevado e portanto, acredito que no R seja possível, ainda que menos intuitivamente que softwares *click to do*.

> Portanto, é possível inserir essas linhas com alguma função do básico ou algum pacote específico é necessário?

Comment: O pacote ggpubr faz o que precisa. Cheque a documentação (em inglês): https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como está no comentário do [Carlos Eduardo Lagosta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/401471/como-inserir-linhas-nos-gr%c3%a1ficos-para-denotar-diferen%c3%a7as-post-hoc-entre-grupos-c#comment787908_401471), o pacote `ggpubr` tem uma função, `stat_compare_means` que pode inserir as linhas de comparação. No caso do exemplo abaixo, essas comparações serão as efetuadas por testes t, função `t.test`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

symnum.args <- list(cutpoints = c(0, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 1), 
                    symbols = c("****", "***", "**", "*", "ns"))
comparacoes <- list(c("B", "C"), c("A","C")) 

pl <- ggplot(df,aes(x = Grupo, y = value, fill = Grupo)) + 
  geom_boxplot()

pl + stat_compare_means(aes(label = "p.format"),
                        method = "t.test",
                        symnum.args = symnum.args,
                        comparisons = comparacoes)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para não sobrepor as linhas talvez o seguinte exemplo seja útil. A parte importante são as instruções onde se calculam `lab.y1`.

```
lab.y1 <- with(df, tapply(value, Grupo, max))
lab.y1 <- ceiling(combn(lab.y1, 2, max)) + c(0, 0.25, 1)
lab.y2 <- max(lab.y1) + 1
comparacoes2 <- list(c("A", "B"), c("B", "C"), c("A","C")) 

pl2 <- ggboxplot(df, x = "Grupo", y = "value", fill = "Grupo") +
  stat_compare_means(symnum.args = symnum.args,
                     comparisons = comparacoes2,
                     label.y = lab.y1) 

pl2
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Perfeito @Rui Barradas, já chequei a documentação do ggpub() e na verdade utilizei method = "anova" pq meu df original é composto por 4 grupos. Tudo está ocorrendo bem, exceto que esses elementos de significância (" *** " e "ns") não consigo descobrir como chegar até eles para editá-los. As linhas em si já identifiquei que posso afastá-las umas das outras utilizando "label.y = c()" mas quando ajusto o gráfico para escalas menores de visualização estes elementos de significância ficam sobrepondo as linhas e misturando-se. Ainda estou em busca de descobrir como posso editá-los!

Comment: @gleidsonmr Veja o novo exemplo. Não passa de um modo de calcular a localização das linhas. Mas este tipo de problemas dificilmente tem uma solução geral, é preciso experimentar e ajustar.

Answer (score 1):

Sua resposta @Rui Barradas, me permitiu pensar uma forma que seria alterar em "x" o posicionamento. De todo modo envio a figura para que vc observe o que acontece com os "***" e com os "ns" e não exatamente as linhas... pq como disse anteriormente eu até consigo afastar as linhas umas das outras, mas as fontes destes elementos não consegui ainda acessar. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observe as figuras "A,B,C e D" que são justamente as menores e por isso está um pouco poluído.

A figura E devido o tamanho, não gerou problema.